# Test Dsc custom Resources

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am new in DSC custom resources.

I created 1 custom dsc resource and put into **C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules** path
file created for custom resource code is below

`

```
function Set-TargetResource
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.String]
        $ServerURL,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.String]
        $ResultFilePath
    )
    Try
    {
        $res=Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $ServerURL -Filter "Name = 'wuauserv'"

        if($res.Status -eq "OK")
        {
            if((Test-Path $ResultFilePath))
            {
                Out-File $ResultFilePath -InputObject "$ServerURL is Running"
            }
            else
            {
                New-Item -Path $ResultFilePath -ItemType file -Value "$ServerURL is Running"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if((Test-Path $ResultFilePath))
            {
                Out-File $ResultFilePath -InputObject "$ServerURL is not Running"
            }
            else
            {
                New-Item -Path $ResultFilePath -ItemType file -Value "$ServerURL is not Running"
            }
        }
    }
    Catch
    {
            if((Test-Path $ResultFilePath))
            {
                Out-File $ResultFilePath -InputObject "$ServerURL is not Running"
            }
            else
            {
                New-Item -Path $ResultFilePath -ItemType file -Value "$ServerURL is not Running"
            }
    }
```

}

`

And usage of DSC resource file is below

```
Configuration ServerTest
{ 

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
        $MachineName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
        $ServerIPOrMachineName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
        $ResultFilePath


    )
    #param ($MachineName="localhost") 
    Try
    {
        Import-DscResource -ModuleName ServerStatusDSCmodule
        node "localhost" 
        { 
             ServerStatusDSCResource MyServerTest 
             { 
                ServerURL =  $ServerIPOrMachineName
                ResultFilePath = $ResultFilePath
             }
        } 

     }
     Catch
     {

     }

}
ServerTest
```

This will create Servertest folder and localhost.mof but when I run **Start-DscConfiguration -Path "D:\ServerTest\"** it will not able to create file given to $ResultFilePath

Comment: Did you specify parameters to ServerTest when you invoked it (the step that generated the mof file)

Answer (score 0):

I found my error when Test function returns false then only set function invoke and in my Test function it always returns true.